# Call a function before .onChange in DatePicker

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I've made it so whenever I change the date in DatePicker, Xcode prints the chosen date like this:

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, in: range, displayedComponents: .date)
        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
        .onChange(of: date) {
            print(date)
            print($0)
        }
```

However, when the view first appears, I want to print the date that is chosen by default (today's date). What can I do to print the default date before I change the date in DatePicker?

Also, since I'm at it. Why is it that whenever I remove print($0), I get the following error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type '()'`

Comment: Regarding your second question: if you type `print($0)`, you're implicitly using the closure parameter. However, if you don't use `$0` anywhere, you need to explicitly ignore the parameter like `.onChange(of: date) { _ in`. Or better use it like `.onChange(of: date) { value in`.

Answer (score 0):

Alt 1:

```
.onAppear{ print(date) }
```

Alt 2:

```
  .onChange(of: date) { [date] newDate in
                        print("From \(date) to \(newDate)" )
                    }
```

=> in this way both values you want will be shown.
Hope this also answer your question2.

Comment: Hi @Neocoleoidea, I ended up using .onReceive. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @NicoCobelo It's useful if you post your solution when you have found it...